# Loudspeaker electro-magnetic waves noise isolation

Tags: noise, sound

I read about the  magnetic waves created by Loudspeakers, causes noise in electronics circuit. If a speaker is going to be soldered in-place with all other circuit components, how can the noise be isolated from the circuit?

Comment: are you certain that the interference is caused by a fluctuating magnetic field?

Comment: @jsotola I read it somewhere, i have not actually experienced this personally

Comment: The **DC field** from the **magnet** can possibly affect magnetic cores nearby. I discovered *that* when a small loudspeaker passed over a T-50-6 toroid core that was the primary inductive reactance of a 3 MHz oscillator.

Comment: @user241802  Could you post a link or a reference to where you've read it?  That will give a better context to the question, and you'll get better answers.

Comment: @user241802 the book is **Encyclopedia of Electronics component volume 2**